# Google anlytics monitor particular url

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

In my site i want to monitor a particular url,in google anlytics there is an option as goal set but my url is somewhat like this

```
          http://www.xyz/support/1
          http://www.xyz/support/123
          http://www.xyz/support/214
          http://www.xyz/support/11
```

How to monitor the time spent on the url http://www.xyz/support/

Is it enough that we specify http://www.xyz/support/ only in the goal set url field..

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this, perhaps the cleanest way is to just ***create an additional Profile/Report*** (which you can call *Support*), then immediately set a filter against that Profile. All you need to is supply a name for the filter and then input your subdirectory (in the 'subdirectory' textbox, see below). In that textbox, you can enter the subdirectory itself or give a regexp instead (e.g., ***^support/*.?$*** depending on the Default Page setting for that Profile).

Of course, this Profile won't populate immediately, so to test the value you input to *subdirectory*, i would recommend testing it 'live' in your main Profile, using the filter textbox at the bottom of the Report Tables.

[image]

Comment: I have added a profile already.So adding this filter,will it cause the report to produce only this data??

Comment: that is correct. Your Profile will include unfiltered data for those days prior to setting this filter, therefore, i always prefer to create a new Profile then immediately set a filter against it. I have edited my answer to answer your question above in more detail.